# Rails raw SQL: Limit Join query to first record

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have generated SQL JOIN statements that work just fine. Now I want to use `LIMIT` with them but no matter what I do it doesn't work.

One of those statement kinda look like this:

```
JOIN pet ON pet.human_id = humans.id
```

This works perfectly fine. I can get all the pets someone has with it (the actual query is a bit bigger tho). Now, I only want the first pet. I tried these things:

```
JOIN pet ON pet.human_id = humans.id LIMIT 1 --> Invalid Sql
JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM pet) ON pet.human_id = humans.id --> Invalid Sql
JOIN (SELECT * FROM pet LIMIT 1) ON pet.human_id = humans.id --> []
```

But they don't work and

I CANNOT USE `.limit(1)` since the queries are generated and put in an array which I then make into a long String called `query` and execute that String via `.joins(query)`

I use MariaDB btw

Comment: The following query worked for me, assuming you have a humans has_many pets relation. `result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM humans JOIN pets ON pets.human_id = humans.id LIMIT 1")`

Comment: On MySQL I would use LATERAL but that may not be available on MariaDB. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cnMJuG5h9M9L33NJSdzgz9/0